# Where did Jean-Hugues Anglade appear cameo in Léon: The Professional?

Tags: cameo, leon-the-professional

[Jean-Hugues Anglade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Hugues_Anglade) is listed to appear cameo in [*Léon: The Professional*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on:_The_Professional) but I can't spot him.

Which scene(s) can he be seen in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found him. He was just one of those guys whose apartments Leon and Mathilda broke into (and, presumably, "cleaned"). At 1:21:38 in the 2:12:53 long version of the movie:

[image]

I don't know though why this is called "cameo". Clearly he is not playing himself but just yet another drug dealer or criminal that someone paid to be killed.

Comment: A cameo does not mean someone is playing themselves. It just means that a big-name actor/celebrity is doing a bit-part.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Good to learn that. My definition of "cameo" was provided (incorrectly) verbally by someone decades ago, and I never tested it until now.

Comment: In the case of a celebrity cameo it is often that they play (a version of) themselves, so it is not surprising that people assume that this is what it means. It's not like the word is used every day.